# Consuming Data Services from Windows Phone, versions of data schema: IExtensibleDataObject alternative?

Tags: silverlight, azure, windows-phone

I'm accessing Azure storage (table) from my windows phone azure app, using System.Data.Services.Client dll, via DataServiceContext.

My problem is that in my data classes I can't use IExtensibleDataObject as it's not supported in Silverlight.

Applying XmlSerializerFormat attribute also doesn't affect it, seems like it is ignored when using data services (Fiddler shows that the data is not really in XML format).

Is there a way I can prevent my app from crushing each time a new field is added to the table?

Answer (score 0):

The type IExtensibleDataObject isn't available in the Silverlight Windows Phone version of WCF. If you have an error regarding this type, you should be able to regenerate the proxy class.

You can regenerate your proxy class by using the "Add Service Reference" option in the WP project on Visual Studio.

You can also use the Windows Phone service utility. Mine was found here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\SlSvcUtil.exe

Comment: Regeneration is not an option. And I can add new fields by hand to proxy class. What I need is my class to not crash when a new column is added to the tables